# A coloured textured background image

Tags: css, textures, masking

I have found an image that I want to colour. Can I change the colour of the image without having to edit it in an application such as Photoshop. For example.

```
background-image: url('texture.png');
background-color: blue;
```

And then use this for multiple sections but changing the colour each time?
Just wondering if this is possible and if somebody can tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options (or three).

**Background Image with Overlay gradient**

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  color: white;
}
.bg-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)), url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/patterns_wavy_background_texture_metal_silver_18405_1920x1080.jpg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-gradient"></div>
```

**Pseudo-element with bg image and CSS filters**

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  color:white;
}


.pseudo {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
}

.pseudo:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 background:url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/patterns_wavy_background_texture_metal_silver_18405_1920x1080.jpg);
    background-size: 100% auto;
  }

.pseudo.blue {
  -webkit-filter:sepia(1) hue-rotate(90deg);
          filter:sepia(1) hue-rotate(90deg);
  
}


.pseudo.purple {
  -webkit-filter:sepia(1) hue-rotate(270deg);
          filter:sepia(1) hue-rotate(270deg);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="pseudo blue">Text</div>

<div class="pseudo purple">Text</div>
```

**Background Blend Mode**

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode)

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  color: white;
}
.blend {
  background-image: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/patterns_wavy_background_texture_metal_silver_18405_1920x1080.jpg);
  background-color: #663399;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="blend"></div>
```